# Search for image selection tool in macOS like gwenview

Tags: macos, image

I numerically generate many images where the set of parameters is encoded in the filenames (e.g. mf2d-m_100-r_9.5-mf_1-ph_0-c_0.7-....png)

On Linux I can conveniently browse my images with gwenview with the option to scale the preview size and add several filters (in my case name based).

Is there something similar for macOS with scalable preview size and file selection filter? Finder seems to be inappropriate.

Comment: Presumably you could run `docker` with a Debian image and `gwenview` installed on that. Or a VirtualBox? Or you could try out `feh`.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, probably parallels would be better integrated into macOS. I installed feh via brew but have a xserver problem with it I could not solve yet.

Comment: `feh` is X11-based, so you need XQuartz with that. Also available via **homebrew**. I tried `gwenview` under `docker` and that seems to run fine, btw. It also requires XQuartz.

Comment: I have feh running and it is good for quick browsing. Thanks for the idea! For me parallels is easier than docker w.r.t. graphics and host filesystem access but thanks again for that idea.

Comment: No problems - good luck with your Mac!